# How to make this div be fixed always on the top of all element on the webpage?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Getting This Output on my Blog. (Language is Bengali)
I want it to float always on the front of all element. But Some Contents are overriding it. how to solve it?
Blog: `http://www.blogger-tawsif.ga/`

Code is,

```
<div class="grplusbd_floating_likebox">
                    <span class="iconContainer">
                        <img class="ico" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jpijNi_XBh4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAB_0/P3R_olWI_KI/s512-c/photo.jpg"/>         
                    </span>
<iframe id="floatfollow" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="50" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftawsif.torabi&amp;width=64&amp;height=65&amp;layout=box_count&amp;size=small&amp;show_faces=true&amp;appId=164293520647951" style="border:none;overflow:hidden; vertical-align: middle; float: right;" width="64"></iframe>
</br>
<span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">
Tawsif Torabi
</span>
</br>
<small style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">
Web Developer, GR+ Bangladesh
</small>
</div>
<style>
.grplusbd_floating_likebox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 500px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.93);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px black;
}
.iconContainer {
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img.ico{
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 45px;
    width: auto;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You want to set the `z-index`

Comment: Anyone can remove your "right click disabled" with `document.onmousedown=null`.

Comment: And disabling right click is just annoying for end users. @Krii

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Thanks forthe feedback.. I'll remove the JS, but what for the badge? only adding z-index will fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean in front? If so add:

```
z-index: 9999;
```

If top yeah someone already answered the `top` and `left` positions

Comment: I deleted my answer because it appears to be the `front` not the `top`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yeah i figure base on his image note

Comment: Awesome @tawsiftorabi please approve answer